# Facebook integration, Recommend button on specific product page + show the product image

Tags: c#, facebook, webforms

I have a question about how to integrate the facebook plugin, recommendbutton.
I got the code from facebook like button and put it on the page where i want it displayed. But this only creates a like on the current page with a radom picture of the site and text.

I want the button to be associated with the productpicture and description.
Does anyone have a code like this to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the opengraph tags for this. see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ for details.

Comment: how do i dynamically set the url imagepath and description?

Comment: is this a ok solution--> http://www.juje.me/2011/02/adding-facebook-like-button-in-c-net/ ???

Comment: It didnt work. Is it because you have to be logged in to the site?

Comment: nope you dont have to be logged in, did you reset the facebook cache for the meta tags by calling the url on http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Comment: How do i fix that? I used the method in the comment above.

Comment: I meant on my page you have to login to reach the page where the like button is.. how is the work around for this?

Comment: this wont work. facebook must be able to fetch this page. your page also will not be included in the searchengines (intended or not) as it is not fetch able without login. 
What point is it anyway to like something, if other users cant visit this site? You could of course watch for the facebook user agent, and allow him to index the site without login.

Comment: To get more registered users? Make the site more visible. Its a site with functions that require a login. Thans for the help anyway

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://ogp.me/ for a description of the OG meta tags which help Facebook display your product in a more meaningful way. You can test a URL using the debug tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to see whether the OG tags have been added correctly.

If your page is behind a login, you'll need to either have a version of the page that still displays OG tags and basic content when not logged in, or have a rule that shows the correct tags when the User Agent is the Facebook Scraper. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo for info on the User Agent string used.

Comment: how do I use this to get the current page url/description and image? This is static <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>

Comment: You add the metadata to the <head> of your static content, and Facebook will scrape this to create a preview of the content in the correct format. The debug tool will help you see the page as Facebook sees it.

Comment: Hi,  i think facebook can´t scrape the page because of you need to login to the page. How is the work around for this?

Comment: Oh, in this case, you'll need to either have a logged-out version of this page, or make a rule that shows a version of the page for the Facebook scraper. You can detect the scraper's user agent to do this. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I dont really know how to make the rule but i know how to detect the scraper. Do you have a example of how the rule can look like with this scenario?  Would really appreciate it, have been thinking and testing several hours.

Comment: I have no way of knowing what your request-handling stack looks like, but in pseudocode it'd be:

if( useragent == FACEBOOKSCRAPER )
  show OG Metatag Page
else
  show Logged Out Page

Answer (score 0):

Just add data-href to your Facebook like code:

```
            <div id="{{ item.product.code }}"
                    class="fb-like"
                    data-share="false"
                    data-href="{{ url }}"
                    data-width="250"
                    data-show-faces="true">
            </div>
```